# ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence) Node.js, Sequelize and Heroku

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

I am trying to deploy my application to Heroku, the problem is when my application is trying to connect to the local SQL Server database doesn't work.

When i test my application on development environment everything works good, the connection to the localhost:1433 works correctly.

This is my DB config

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

// Connection to SQL Server
const db = new Sequelize('Cafeteria', process.env.SQL_NAME, process.env.SQL_PASS, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mssql',
    // logging: false,
});

module.exports = db;
```

Connection in server.js

```
// Connection to DB
async dbConnection() {

    try {
        
        await db.authenticate();
        console.log('Database online');

    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error( error );
    }

}
```

And this is the error on console (Heroku logs)

> (node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error:
> SequelizeConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could
> not connect (sequence) at Server.dbConnection
> (/app/models/server.js:43:19) at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) { code: 'ESOCKET' }

Yes the TCP/IP is Enabled, the TCP Port is 1433, TCP Dynamic Ports are a blank space.

The SQL Server Browser is running.

I hope anyone can help me!

Comment: Does Heroku host SQL Server databases locally? I thought the [MSSQL add-on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mssql) linked to Azure SQL databases, so they aren't likely to connect via localhost [127.0.0.1].

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks man, I had no idea that heroku doesn't host mssql databases locally. I'm still learning about SQL bases and heroku. Thank you!!